# Why do i receive an overflow exception when I run this program outputting all words starting with b?

Tags: java, string, exception, overflow

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class vrzbi {
    public static void main(String[]args){
        System.out.println("write a sentence");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String sentence = input.nextLine();
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < sentence.length(); i++) {
            if ( sentence.charAt(i-1) == ' ' && sentence.charAt(i) == 'b'){
                j = i;
                while (sentence.charAt(j) != ' ' && j<sentence.length()){

                    System.out.print(sentence.charAt(j));
                    j++;
                }
                System.out.println(" ");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

The correct words show up : ex. Brother Bob has a baby boy outputs Bob baby boy. But after that I get an overflow exception error at the while line.

Comment: I noticed it does not output Brother as well in the output  Bob baby boy. Is it supposed to?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `j` can take a value equals to `sentence.length()`, so in the while line you should first check the `j<sentence.length()` condition, and then `sentence.charAt(j) != ' '`  since the while conditions are evaluated from left to right.

Change your while

```
while (sentence.charAt(j) != ' ' && j<sentence.length())
```

To

```
while (j<sentence.length() && sentence.charAt(j) != ' ')
```